# My Java code is giving me an out of bounds error

Tags: java, computer-science

How can I find out why this keeps giving me out of bounds errors?

If anyone can, could someone give me advice on how to shorten the the code and make it more efficient? This is for my Computer Science II APA class.

```
import java.util.*;
class arrays15
{

/* write a method that will find the largest values
 *  between two ints.
 */
public static int large(int num1, int num2) {
    return Math.max(num1, num2);
}
```

Assignment:

```
/* fun will take two int arrays and for each position
 * it will compare the two values from each array and put the
 * larger of the two in a new array. If there are not two values
 * to compare then take then assume the other value is a zero (0).
 *  
 * Must call another method to find largest.
 */

 public static int[] fun(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {



    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int g = 0; g < nums1.length; g++) {
        a.add(nums1[g]);
    }
    for(int h = 0; h < nums2.length; h++) {
        b.add(nums1[h]);
    }
    for(int i = a.size(); i < b.size(); i++) {
        a.add(0);
    }
    for(int i = b.size(); i < a.size(); i++) {
        b.add(0);
    }
    int[] r = new int[a.size()];
    for(int j = 0; j < r.length; j++) {
        r[j] = large(a.remove(0), b.remove(0));
    }
    return r;
 }
```

Tests

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] one = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int[] two = new int[]{-1, 3, -4, 8, -5, 6, 7};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(one) + " << >> " + Arrays.toString(two));
    System.out.println("maximusArray: " + Arrays.toString(fun(one,two))); // [1, 3, 3, 8, 5, 6, 7]
    System.out.println();

    one = new int[]{-13, -14, -15, 16};
    two = new int[]{};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(one) + " << >> " + Arrays.toString(two));
    System.out.println("maximusArray: " + Arrays.toString(fun(one,two)));// {0, 0, 0, 16}
    System.out.println();

    one = new int[]{11, 22, 33};
    two = new int[]{-5, 55, 41, -30, 13};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(one) + " << >> " + Arrays.toString(two));
    System.out.println("maximusArray: " + Arrays.toString(fun(one,two)));// {11, 55, 41, 0, 13}
    System.out.println();

}
}
```

The error message is: 
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
at arrays15.fun(Arrays_Lab15_maximusArrays.java:33)
at arrays15.main(Arrays_Lab15_maximusArrays.java:52)

Comment: Which line gives you an out-of-bounds error? Please edit your post to include that.

Comment: I would urge you to improve your post - it is admittedly answered, but you have three close votes already, and only two more are needed. We need the details to make this question useful for readers other than yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Out-of-bound errors means you're probably not accessing indices right, so check which of your data structures are vulnerable to that.
2. Study the error message you get because that at least shows the line where the error happens (would have been better if it was included in the post).

It seems the second for-loop in the fun method is causing the error:

```
for(int h = 0; h < nums2.length; h++) {
    b.add(nums1[h]);
}
```

Why is `nums1` being referenced instead of `nums2`?

Comment: This looks pretty helpful, but if you do not yet have enough information to answer, it is better to wait until you do. If the OP does not add clarifications now, you'll be left with an answer that will contain requests for clarification in perpetuity.

Comment: Thank you M.M.! your answer helped me a lot! It solved my issue. Thank you!

Comment: @ıllıllıкιмσтσıllıllı welcome and hope it helps for the future too

Comment: @halfer you're right. I just wanted to increase my rep so I can do basic SO stuff. Next goal is 50 so I can comment. Until then, I'll stay living on the edge :-)