# comparing elements of the same array in java using single for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, time-complexity, comparison

**comparing elements of the same array in java using single for loop**

```
   a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
   if(a[i]=a[i+1])
      { // some stuff}
```

**Array out of bound exception occur how to resolve this**

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. Please [edit] and make it a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My Java code is giving me an out of bounds error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52709381/my-java-code-is-giving-me-an-out-of-bounds-error)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the code above. Hopefully this will get you on the right track.

```
// Indentation makes code more readable.
public void test ()
{
    // Need to declare the type of variable a.
    // Need to use braces for data definition.
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    // Iteration stops at the second to last element
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++)
    {
        // Use == for comparison. The = is for assignment.
        if (a[i] == a[i + 1])
        { 
            // some stuff}
        }
    }
}
```